# How to use NAnt with C# 4.0 and Mono?

Tags: c#, build, mono, nant

According to the [NAnt website](http://nant.sourceforge.net/), NAnt supports .Net Framework 4.0 but only the Mono 3.5 Profile.  Is there any way to use NAnt while developing a C# 4.0 app using Mono 2.8?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [premake](http://industriousone.com/premake) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to XBuild, http://www.mono-project.com/Microsoft.Build

Or help NAnt and fill in the gaps.